# how can i show the result of input by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, rest

I have a form with two variable (name and namespace) which i want to send it to the server by PUT method and get the result in the same page after clicking to add the variable:

javascript:

```
var $name=$('#Name');
var $namesp=$('#NameSpace');

        $('.button6').on('click', function() {
                 var a=$name.val();
                 var b=$namesp.val();
                 var c=a+"/"+c
           if (confirm('Do you sure ?')) {
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'PUT',
                    url: 'http://rest/'+c,
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function(data1) {
                     $("#orders").append(data1+"its works");
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        console.log("error");
                },
            });
           };
       });
```

HTML:

```
<input id="Name"  type="text" >

<input id="NameSpace"  type="text" >

<div id="orders"><div>
```

Comment: What part are you having problems with? So far you have just dumped the source code, explained you want to display the results but what problem are you having? Have you checked your browser console for errors?

Comment: You aren't sending any data. What is json structure that is expected at server? And as already mentioned you need to define a proper problem statement and actual question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're missing the `data` option in the jQuery ajax call.

```
        $.ajax({
                type: 'PUT',
                url: 'http://rest/'+c,
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function(data1) {
                    $("#orders").append(data1+"its works");
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log("error");
                },
                data: { a: a,
                        b: b,
                        c: c
                      }
        });
```